# Magento 2: Disable all methods when free shipping method is applicable

Tags: shipping-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-2.0, free-shipping

We're using following table rates for our store and these are working fine.

When weight is 0-1(kg) , rate will be 4.5
When weight is 1.1- ~ (kg), rate will be 4.9

[image]

We also enabled Free shipping when price is greater than $100. Now when price is greater than $100, it shows both table rates and free shipping. We need to just show the free shipping when it is applicable and discard table rates when price is greater than $100. How can we achieve this?

Using Cart rule, it still shows the table rate method and just set the price to 0. How can I show the Free Shipping as method?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this and its working fine.

```
<preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" type="Package\Namespace\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" />
```